# Suppress "stack size cannot be dynamically determined" warnings?

Tags: cuda, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, nvcc

I'm getting a CUDA warning saying

```
ptxas warning : Stack size for entry function '_Z13a_test_kernelv' cannot be
statically determined.
```

Now, I know what it means, and there's a [SO question about why it happens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9950599/1593077). What I want to suppress the warning (when compiling with nvcc 10.x). Can I? If so, where exactly do I put the warning suppression `#pragma` for this?

Comment: Dynamic memory allocation doesn't cause that warning, recursion does

Comment: @talonmies: First answer in the SO question about this says dynamic allocation, and I don't think I have recursion in my code, but I might be wrong. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Add `--nvlink-options -suppress-stack-size-warning` when compiling with nvcc.

Comment: ... but wouldn't that disable other warnings about stack size?

Comment: `-suppress-stack-size-warning, Suppress the warning that otherwise is printed when stack size cannot be determined.` I haven't encountered other warnings about stack size yet. Sorry I don't know if there's a `#pragma` way to suppress the warning...

Comment: There is, I was just worried this would suppress warnings in other problematic situations.