# How can I disable the ptxas warning about indeterminable stack size?

Tags: cuda, compiler-warnings, nvcc, ptxas, assembler-warnings

When compiling CUDA device code, you may get the error (with line break for readability):

```
ptxas warning : Stack size for entry function '_ZN7kernels11print_stuffIiEEvv' 
cannot be statically determined
```

This can have [several reasons, like dynamic memory allocation or use of recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950599/cuda-ptxas-warnings-stack-size-for-entry), but those don't matter right now. I want to disable the warning, within some function at least. The thing is, I don't know which token to use to do so. It's no use searching [this list](http://www.ssl.berkeley.edu/~jimm/grizzly_docs/SSL/opt/intel/cc/9.0/lib/locale/en_US/mcpcom.msg) (following [the suggestion here SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17095910/1593077) about disabling specific warnings) - because those are warnings in the C/C++ front-end of NVCC, not the assembler.

So how *can* I disable this warning?

Comment: Obviously what you linked to irrelevant, Those are for disabling C or C++ warnings from the CUDA front end. Your warning comes from the assembler......

Comment: @talonmies: Will edit to clarify that.

Comment: @talonmies: Are you sure? If so, make that an answer please.

Comment: what was the problem with the answer given to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328507/suppress-stack-size-cannot-be-dynamically-determined-warnings) ?  Because you want something that works on a per-function basis, like a pragma?  Or that you were concerned that it might suppress "other" stack size warnings (not sure what those would be)?  Or something else?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: The edit history is informative here. Originally the question was insinuating that there would be a pragma or front end option  to suppress this warning, which is obviously impossible. Still, when someone has asked over 350 questions on this tag, I guess it might be difficult to remember all the questions they have already asked and had answered....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important point to note is that this is an *assembler* warning, so none of the usual front end warning  suppression options are relevant.

`ptxas` only supports a very limited number of warning control options. Prior to CUDA 9, only the following were supported:

```
--suppress-double-demote-warning                    (-suppress-double-demote-warning)
        Suppress the warning that is otherwise emitted when a double precision instruction
        is encountered in PTX that is targeted for an SM version that does not have
        double precision support

--disable-warnings                                  (-w)                        
        Inhibit all warning messages.

--warn-on-double-precision-use                      (-warn-double-usage)        
        Warning if double(s) are used in an instruction.

--warn-on-local-memory-usage                        (-warn-lmem-usage)          
        Warning if local memory is used.

--warn-on-spills                                    (-warn-spills)              
        Warning if registers are spilled to local memory.

--warning-as-error                                  (-Werror)                   
        Make all warnings into errors.
```

In your case the only option would be to suppress all warnings. Adding `-Xptxas='-w'` to any `nvcc` invocation should achieve that.

CUDA 9 and newer add another option `ptxas` which suppresses the warning you ask about:

```
--suppress-stack-size-warning                       (-suppress-stack-size-warning)
        Suppress the warning that otherwise is printed when stack size cannot be
        determined.
```

In this case, adding `-Xptxas='-suppress-stack-size-warning'` to any `nvcc` invocation should eliminate the warning.

Comment: @einpoklum: I missed that `-suppress-stack-size-warning` was added to CUDA 9 (I was regression testing against CUDA 8 when I ran `ptxas -h`). So what you want already exists. But you should already know this from the almost identical question you asked a couple of weeks ago.