Register usage for arrays in CUDA
How do arrays map to GPU registers in NVIDIA GPUs (and in AMD GPUs when using OpenCL) ?
So when I define an array like uint8_t X[64], is it stored in 16 32-bit registers (4 bytes per register) or in 64 (1 byte per reg)?
When I try to define different array size, the reg count changed not linearly. But the feeling is that the values are not packed in registers, i.e. only 1 element fits into each register.

This cannot be answered without some specific code. Rather than packing (which implies the use of integer vector instructions) I would suspect that the compiler reuses the same register for different array entries at different points during the runtime. That assumes that the array is not spilled onto the stack in the first place

@Homer512, the array can be either on the stack or in registers, right? Let's assume that the compiler still decided to place the array in registers. How will the values be distributed in the registers?

I don't think Nvidia has disclosed the register allocation algorithm. You have to observe it in real code, e.g. here on Godbolt there is one full register per variable but the numbering is arbitrary

@Homer512, the GPU register allocation rules are documented in the CUDA programming guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses

@Johan local memory is in fact implemented as a stack. You can see it in error messages such as the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950599/cuda-ptxas-warnings-stack-size-for-entry Of course this is an implementation detail but in that case C/C++ also doesn't have a stack, they have automatic storage

@Johan ARM doesn't have push and pop either, just macros for regular memory operations, it still works with a stack. Same with most RISC. In SASS register R1 acts as a stack pointer of sorts. You are right that normally device functions don't grow or shrink the stack, instead letting the kernel entry point do it. But you can still see it in action, for example by using alloca

It is tempting to think of the CUDA register file as the GPU's alternative to the CPU's stack, but is is really not, it rather maps exactly to the CPU's registers. Except of course that the GPU has 256 addressable registers per thread (max) and (most) CPUs have fewer.
Arrays are not mapped to registers.
According to: Local memory and register spilling
On page 5:

Arrays declared inside kernels, if compiler can’t resolve indexing

Registers aren’t indexable, so have to be placed in LMEM


The CUDA programming guide says:

Automatic variables that the compiler is likely to place in local memory are:

Arrays for which it cannot determine that they are indexed with constant quantities


LMEM here is the local memory, which is backed by the main memory, and cached in the L1 + L2 cache.
Unless your array accessed can all be deduced at compile time, it will not be stored in registers, but rather in local (read: global) memory.
You want to avoid register spilling at all costs, because every access to the L2 cache takes 400 cycles, and global memory takes more. It is rare for local memory to stay in the L1 cache, because it is so small and so oversubscribed.
Also registers are not shared between threads (except for universal registers, which are guaranteed to hold the same value for all threads), so you cannot use this to use your array to share data between threads.
See: CUDA C++ programming guide:

Because it is on-chip, shared memory has much higher bandwidth and much lower latency than local or global memory.

The solution is to store your array in __shared__ memory. This is much faster than local memory, and will never get evicted from a cache.
__shared__ uint8_t myarray[64]; //takes up 64 bytes
const auto a = myarray[threadIdx.x]; //uses up 1 32-bit register per thread. 

However using an array of uint8_t, causes a problem: shared memory bank conflicts.
It is 4x faster to store your 8-bit entries like so:
__shared__ uint32_t myarray[64]; //takes up 256 bytes
const auto a = myarray[threadIdx.x]; //uses up 1 32-bit register per thread. 


To answer your second question, the GPU only has 32-bit registers. A 64-bit value gets stored in two adjacent registers. But smaller values always use up a 32-bit register.
The only exception is booleans, which are stored in 1 bit predicate registers, if used in an if-then scenario.
I don't know about AMD/OpenCL, but I suspect it to be the same, at least when running OpenCL on GPUs.

Depending on the code/algorithm one might be able to use uchar4 to get both efficient access and space efficiency.

"Except of course that the GPU has 256 register (max)" -- that is the per thread limited. The per SM  register file is much, much large than that.

@Johan, thank you ;)
